# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'INotifyWrapper'

Tags: python, django

I have installed python(2.7.9) and Django package(1.10.5). But when i execute the Django commands, i am getting below error.

```
Command: python -m django --version

Error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__main__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.core import management   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.utils import autoreload, lru_cache, six   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 61, in <module>
    fd = pyinotify.INotifyWrapper.create().inotify_init() AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'INotifyWrapper'

Command:  /usr/local/bin/django-admin

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 7, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.utils import autoreload, lru_cache, six   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 61, in <module>
    fd = pyinotify.INotifyWrapper.create().inotify_init() AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'INotifyWrapper'
```

Comment: Same question here ...